# How do I reset default configuration provided by Mac OS x?

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I have just messed up with default apache server and PHP. MAMP is working perfectly. But I want to run it on default mode because of some other setups. Is there any way to do so?

I tried this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/how-to-revert-default-mac-apache-install-to-original

but, it's not working. I can't see anything while loading the localhost page.